# Pandas reverse of diff()

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have calculated the differences between consecutive values in a series, but I cannot reverse / undifference them using `diffinv()`:

```
ds_sqrt = np.sqrt(ds)
ds_sqrt = pd.DataFrame(ds_sqrt)
ds_diff = ds_sqrt.diff().values
```

How can I undifference this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [opposite of df.diff() in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428679/opposite-of-df-diff-in-pandas)

Answer (score 14):

You can do this via `numpy`. Algorithm [courtesy of @Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43563293/9209546).

Of course, you need to know the first item in your series for this to work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)})
df['B'] = df['A'].diff()

x, x_diff = df['A'].iloc[0], df['B'].iloc[1:]
df['C'] = np.r_[x, x_diff].cumsum().astype(int)

#    A    B  C
# 0  8  NaN  8
# 1  5 -3.0  5
# 2  4 -1.0  4
# 3  3 -1.0  3
# 4  9  6.0  9
# 5  7 -2.0  7
# 6  4 -3.0  4
# 7  0 -4.0  0
# 8  8  8.0  8
# 9  1 -7.0  1
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use diff_inv from pmdarima.[Docs link](https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.utils.diff_inv.html)

```
# genarating random table
  np.random.seed(10)
  vals = np.random.randint(1, 10, 6)
  df_t = pd.DataFrame({"a":vals})

  #creating two columns with diff 1 and diff 2
  df_t['dif_1'] = df_t.a.diff(1)
  df_t['dif_2'] = df_t.a.diff(2)

  df_t

    a   dif_1   dif_2
  0 5   NaN     NaN
  1 1   -4.0    NaN
  2 2   1.0    -3.0
  3 1   -1.0    0.0
  4 2   1.0     0.0
  5 9   7.0     8.0
```

Then create a function that will return an array with inverse values of diff.

```
from pmdarima.utils import diff_inv

def inv_diff (df_orig_column,df_diff_column, periods):
    # Generate np.array for the diff_inv function - it includes first n values(n = 
    # periods) of original data & further diff values of given periods
    value = np.array(df_orig_column[:periods].tolist()+df_diff_column[periods:].tolist())

    # Generate np.array with inverse diff
    inv_diff_vals = diff_inv(value, periods,1 )[periods:]
    return inv_diff_vals
```

Example of Use:

```
# df_orig_column - column with original values
# df_diff_column - column with differentiated values
# periods - preiods for pd.diff()
inv_diff(df_t.a, df_t.dif_2, 2)
```

Output:

```
array([5., 1., 2., 1., 2., 9.])
```

Answer (score 5):

**Reverse diff in one line with pandas**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([10, 15, 14, 18], columns = ['Age'])
df['Age_diff'] = df.Age.diff()

df['reverse_diff'] = df['Age'].shift(1) + df['Age_diff']

print(df)

    Age  Age_diff  reverse_diff
0   10       NaN           NaN
1   15       5.0          15.0
2   14      -1.0          14.0
3   18       4.0          18.0
```

Comment: This makes kind of no sense to me as you use the target ['Age'] as an input to reproduce itself. I think the goal is to reproduce a series without already having it. Otherwise it is kind of "how to break into your own house with your key". Or do i miss something?

Comment: yes, you are right, but there are no any conditions in question

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example.

First, let's import needed packages

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import pmdarima as pm

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
```

Then, let's create a simple discretized cosine wave

```py
period = 5
cycles = 7
x = np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi*cycles, periods*cycles+1))
X = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

and plot

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
ax.plot(X, marker='.')
ax.set(
    xticks=X.index
)
ax.axvline(0, color='r', ls='--')
ax.axvline(period, color='r', ls='--')
ax.set(
    title='Original data'
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that the period is `5`. Let's now remove this "seasonality" by differentiating with period 5

```py
X_diff = X.diff(periods=period)
# NOTE: the first `period` observations
#       are needed for back transformation
X_diff.iloc[:period] = X[:period]
```

Note that we have to keep the first `period` observations to allow back transformation. If you don't need them you have to keep them elsewhere and then concatenate when you want to back transform.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
ax.axvline(0, color='r', ls='--')
ax.axvline(period-1, color='r', ls='--')
ax.plot(X_diff, marker='.')
ax.annotate(
    'Keep these original data\nto allow back transformation',
    xy=(period-1, .5), xytext=(10, .5),
    arrowprops=dict(color='k')
)
ax.set(
    title='Transformed data'
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Let's now back transform data with `pmdarima.utils.diff_inv`

```py
X_diff_inv = pm.utils.diff_inv(X_diff, lag=period)[period:]
```

Note that we discard the first `period` results that would be `0` and not needed.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
ax.axvline(0, color='r', ls='--')
ax.axvline(period-1, color='r', ls='--')
ax.plot(X_diff_inv, marker='.')
ax.set(
    title='Back transformed data'
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting different plots using your code

Answer (score 0):

I think some examples may overcomplicate? The inverse of differentiating is simple integrating. But for this you need a starting value, so to say the `const` part when integrating `dx = f(x) + const`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some example data
input = pd.Series([5., 1., 2., 1., 2., 9.])

# saving the offset ('const' part of integral) to reconstruct
offset = input[0]

# differentiating
diff = input.diff()

# the first row after diff() will always be NaN, it is reasonable to set this to zero
diff[0] = 0 

# => reconstruct (reverse diff / integrate) <=
reverse_diff_no_offset = diff.cumsum()
reverse_diff = reverse_diff_no_offset + offset

# plot: You can see why a offset is needed. Any other offset will shift the line up/down
plt.plot(input, color='green', linestyle=None, marker="o")
plt.plot(reverse_diff_no_offset, color='grey')
plt.plot(reverse_diff, color='blue')
```

[image]

Also numpy has [cumsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html?highlight=cumsum), so it will work there as well

Comment: Update: Just saw that my example is quite similar to the answer of @jpp. However, i use pandas as in the original question

Answer (score 0):

arb = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]})

(-1)*arb['a'].diff(periods=-1)

Output:

3.0

5.0

7.0

9.0

11.0

NaN

Name: a, dtype: float64