# Inverese transformation for time series predictions

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series, data-transform

I have a time-series data for energy consumption. The data is split into sets `training` and `test`. The training set have daily data from `2011-05-01` to `2018-12-30`. The test set have data from `2019-02-01` to `2019-12-30`. Both the sets are in two separate pandas dataframes.

For making the TS stationary, I applied this transformation:

```
train["energy_val"] = train["energy_val"].apply(np.log)
train["energy_val"] = train["energy_val"].diff()
train = train.dropna()
```

I trained a model on top of it with a forecast horizon of 30 days, and got the predictions for the test set.

The test predictions look like this:

```
    date        energy_val 
0   2019-02-01  -0.89123
1   2019-02-02  0.86733
2   2019-02-04  0.32456
3   2019-02-05  -0.51421

...
```

How do I inverse the transformation for the test set? For the test set, I don't know what `prior` value should I use to `undiff` it.

Comment: Why won't you assume something? like an avg for the last week of January across the training data? Or maybe even avg of the readings from the last day of January?

Comment: You mean to say that the average energy value for last week of Jan should be taken as prior to undiff the test values?

Comment: Yes. And you can experiment with various ways at arriving at this prior value. Another approach could be to use the first value from the test set and impute ("undiff") for the rest.

Comment: I already have test predictions. Why imputing would be required? Can you put a figure or simple code so that I can understand clearly?

Comment: Let's start with your piece of code for `undiffing`... Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I will eidt the question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the raw expected values for test dataset, you can use the first value to start calculating ["undiffed" results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428679/opposite-of-df-diff-in-pandas):

```
starting_value = orig_test.loc["energy_val", 0]
test.loc["energy_val", 0] += starting_value

test['undiffed'] = test['energy_val'].rolling(2).sum().shift(-1)
```

Comment: `Assuming you have access to the raw expected values for test dataset`, it is the test set, there are no raw values available for this set

Comment: I explained in the comments above what to do in such a case - e.g. you can pick an average for similar week or month of the year. BTW, if the expected values do not exist - how can you check the predictions are fine on the test set?